# CanCan: Only admin can delete users but he should'nt delete himself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

```
def initialize(user)
 if user.has_role? :admin
  can :manage, :all
  can :destroy, User
  can [:update , :destroy], [Article, Comment]
 else
  can :read, :all
 end
```

how to make only admin delete users but cannot delete himself ?

I am using wice_grid gem and I have added this to my view but still admin can delete himself

```
g.column do |user|
 if can? :destroy, @user && !current_user(user)
  link_to('Delete', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'You sure?' })
 end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def initialize(user)
  if user.has_role? :admin
    can :manage, :all
    cannot :destroy, User, id: user.id 
  else
    can :read, :all
 end

g.column do |user|
  if can? :destroy, user
    link_to('Delete', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'You sure?' })
  end
end
```

Comment: this will allow to delete the others except the current(admin) right ?

Answer (score 1):

Read [Ability-Precedence](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ability-Precedence) for this, BTW you can do this:

```
if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
      cannot :destroy, User, :id => current_user.id
end
```

Thanks

Comment: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Ability:0xb5b1dc20>

Comment: pass your variable, current_user is a variable with devise. use your current_user variable which is @user, I think.

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
def initialize(user)
 if user.has_role? :admin
  can :read, :all
  can [:update, :destroy], [Article, Comment, User]
  cannot :destroy, User, id: user.id # it means do not destroy own-self(the id of object to be deleted is not equal to admin's id)
 else
  can :read, :all
 end
```

don't write 'manage :all', as if found it, control will never go down, means rest of the code will never execute because 'manage :all' means can do everything, on the other hand if you specify like 'can [:update, :destroy], [Article, Comment, User]', it will work in you situation.

Comment: it turned the admin like a normal user

Comment: i mean , it made the admin can read all only , i cannot create user or delete a user